# How to pass Range Values into an HTML sidebar to be ticked or selected then save selections using GAS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the sidebar is open, it displays the colors (color name and its HEX #, which are sitting in a sheet) and displays also a checkbox next to each color.

The user ticks the checkbox or selects the colors how many he/she wants all the way down, clicks on save and the list gets saved into an array...maybe `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()`

Here's the code I got for the sidebar and getting the colors from the range:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function showSideBar() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pickColor');
  var html = tmp.evaluate();
  html.setTitle('Escolha as cores');
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function getColors() {
  const colorListSheet = ss.getSheetByName('CadCores');
  const colorList = colorListSheet.getRange(2,1,colorListSheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  return colorList;
}
```

Here's the html part, whose body I can't make it dynamic being a newbie. Listed Yellow as an example, but I suppose that having the checkbox, the color name and its hex would require it to be a table, correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <input id="Yello" type="checkbox">
  <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button  id='salvar-cores'>Salvar Cores</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <script>
    let colorArray = 10;//But this would be the getColors' length, right?
    function addColor(colors){
      for (let i = 0; i < colorArray; i++){
        $(i + 1).text(colors[i]);
      }
    };
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addColor).getColors();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: As with all html communications, the html has to initiate the interaction.  Or you could reload the sidebar  and reinitialize it with scriplets or with an onLoad or readyState trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work for you

### 1. I got all the colors in a spreadsheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
function showSideBar() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('pickColor');
  var html = tmp.evaluate();
  html.setTitle('Escolha as cores');
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function getColors() {
  const colorListSheet = ss.getSheetByName('CadCores');
  const colorList = colorListSheet.getRange(2,1,colorListSheet.getLastRow() -1,2).getValues();
  return colorList;
}

function onOpen(){
  showSideBar()
}
```

### 2. Render the colors in the DOM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id='color-name'></div>
  <br>
  <button  id='salvar-cores'>Salvar Cores</button>

  <script>
    function afterLoad(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDataReturned).getColors();
    }

    function afterDataReturned(arrayOfArrays){
      const item = document.getElementById("color-name")
      arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(row){

        let input = document.createElement("input")
        input.type = "checkbox"
        input.id = row[0]
        input.value = row[1]
        item.appendChild(input)

        let label = document.createElement("label")
        label.setAttribute('for',row[0])
        label.textContent = row[0]
        item.appendChild(label)

      })
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterLoad)
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### 3. Add any other color you want in the sheet and refresh the menu, so it reloads the new colors

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always put a ballot symbol into a select option and toggle on or off.  Here is an example.

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  try {
    var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Cad Colors");
    menu.addItem("Get Colors", "showGetColors");
    menu.addToUi();
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function showGetColors() {
  try {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_GetColors").evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}

function getColors() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("CadColors");
    return sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function setColors(checked) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("CadColors");
    sh.getRange(2,3,checked.length,1).setValues(checked);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Then if the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="colorSelect" onchange="colorOnChange()" ondblclick="colorDblClick()"></select>
    <input type="button" onclick="colorSaveClick()" value="Save Colors">
    <?!= include("JS_GetColors"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seperated out the javascript in a seperate file that is included into a HTML Template:

```
<script>
  function colorOnChange() {
    try {
      var select = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
      var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
      var text = option.text;
      text = text.charAt(0) === "☐" ? "☑" : "☐";
      text = text.concat(option.text.slice(1));
      option.text = text;
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
  
  function colorDblClick() {
    try {
      var select = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
      var text = select.value;
      var option = null;
      text = text.charAt(0) === "☐" ? "☑" : "☐";
      text = text.concat(select.value.slice(1));
      for( var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++ ) {
        option = select.options[i];
        if( option.text.slice(1) === text.slice(1) ) {
          option.text = text;
          break;
        }
      }
      select.value = text;
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
  
  function colorSaveClick() {
    try {
      var select = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
      var checked = [];
      for( var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++ ) {
        // note that checked is an array of arrays
        checked.push( select.options[i].text.charAt(0) === "☑" ? [true] : [false] );
      }
      google.script.run.setColors(checked);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
  
  (function () {
     try {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
         function (colors) {
           try {
             var option = null;
             var text = null;
             // omit first line
             for( var i=1; i<colors.length; i++ ) {
               option = document.createElement("OPTION");
               text = document.createTextNode("☐ "+colors[i][0]+" "+colors[i][1]);
               option.appendChild(text);
               document.getElementById("colorSelect").appendChild(option);
             }
           }
           catch(err) {
             alert(err);
           }
         }
       ).getColors();
     }
     catch(err) {
       alert(err);
     }
  }());
</script>
```

The only difficulty is handling the select.value.  To toggle it you have to double click.  Every other one you can select and toggle from the drop down.  The status of the selections is returned to the spreadsheet using setColors().

My spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

And the sidebar like this:

[image]